# Sencha Touch Apk and NetworkOnMainThreadException

Tags: javascript, android, html, sencha-touch, apk

I developed a Sencha Touch App that uses network connections to call different web services during login process.
I build native apk with Sencha CMD and it works right in Android 2.3.7 but not in newer versions.
I read that this is a NetworkOnMainThreadException problem.
The solutions I found for Android are:

1) to make webservice calls by implementing AsyncTask.

2) use StrictMode Class in Android and set the policy

But how can apply these solutions in my Sencha Javascript App?
I really hope that someone of you had found a solution!

Thanks for any advice!

> Edit

After some tests I discover that my app works fine in android 2.3.7 but not in android 4 because of one of my webservice.
It's a liferay json web service. It's the fourth web service that i call and if i don't call it my app works fine.
Does someone of you know if the  Android (versions >2.3.7) Web View  doesn't support Liferay Web Service?

Answer (score 1):

I think You're performing network operations on `UI Thread`. This will cause blocking User Interface. Since Android 3.0, performing network operations on `UI Thread` is not applicable and it throws `NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

In the API document, it says:

> Network operations can involve unpredictable delays. To prevent this
>   from causing a poor user experience, always perform network operations
>   on a separate thread from the UI. The AsyncTask class provides one of
>   the simplest ways to fire off a new task from the UI thread.

So you should use `AsyncTask` in order to handle this problem.

Check this out [link](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html#AsyncTask). This can be a sample for writing `AsyncTask`

If you wonder why this procedure is applied and why this exception is thrown. Check [this](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/06/app-force-close-honeycomb-ics.html) out as well.

Hope this may help you!

Comment: thanks gokhanakkurt! I know what is the problem and how to resolve it in java,but not in Sencha/javascript. Right now i'm writing a new android java application and trying to put my app.jar file inside it (I created the jar file from apk using the dextojar tool)

Comment: OK, would like to solve this problem in Sencha Touch? Could you tell me about your problem specifically? What's your purpose?

Comment: The problem is that my sencha app has a login view and after you put username and password my app calls 6 different webservices and then if all it's ok you go to the next view. I know that is a thread problem. I used delayed tasks but it doesn't resolve the problem. My app stucks in login view

Comment: How I said before, my app works fine in Android 2.3.7. Thank you!!